# How to print part of a nested list in Python?

Tags: python, list

so if I have a 2d list like:

```
A =[['   ', '   ', '   '],['   ', '   ', '   '],['   ', '   ', '   '],['   ', '   ', '   ']]
col = 3
```

My code:

```
for i in A:
    print('|', end = '')
    print(*i, sep = '', end = '|\n')
print(' ' + 3* col*'-')
```

This will print the whole list:

How should I modify it so that it just print the last 3 rows

Comment: What about `print(A[-3:])`? Or `print('\n'.join(str(a) for a in A[-3:]))`.

Comment: @Elmex80s ohhh let me try :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the last three rows, which I assume means two rows with "sides" and one row at the bottom, change the line with the `for` statement to:

```
for i in A[-2:]:
```

If you want the last three rows of A itself (in addition to the bottom row of dashes), then

```
for i in A[-3:]:
```

Comment: Thank you! it works, and sorry I can't upvote since my rep is less than 15 omfg /__\